# php- web crawling: discuss "indexing unique URL's" - performance issue

Tags: php, mysql, web-crawler, large-data

(forgive me for the poor english)

I'm operating a custom web-crawler on a specific range of URL's.
I'm testing it and everything is working perfect so far..

Lately i notice a performance issue i want to discuss  - the bots are crawling pages that are indexed 
in a url_pool table, while searching in the target page for the target content the bots saves
the page links that they find if they are not in the table already...
i had some conflict problems while operating several crawl scripts (in the same time) but 
i fixed it.

After crawling about 1.5M pages my url_pool table include almost 5M rows that contains
the url, some "flags" ,url hash(simhash - of 32 digits), domain, etc...

The mysql db table is innodb with large buffers and well indexed according to the search query's.
I'm noticing while monitoring the performance of the bots that the "check if exist" function I use 
to prevent duplicate urls in my table is getting slower and slower.
I know that its obvious that the larger the table the longer it will take to search in it, but it seems too early to see this increase in execution time.

If I summaries the performance:

- url_pool~100K ROWS -> 0.8s for the entire crawling process (1 page).
- url_pool~800K ROWS -> 1.1s
- url_pool~1.8M ROWS -> 1.9s
- url_pool~3.5M ROWS -> 3.2s
- url_pool~5M ROWS -> 4.8s

Another important fact is that while checking if url's exists in the table im not searching using the text, I'm creating the hash and then matching it to others in the table ,I followed an advice I received in the early stage of building the crawler, and found that its improving the performance.

Now, 1.9s for each page is fare (considering running 4 bots together) but 5s is far too slow....

Can you please advice me?

**Edit:**

some more information:

I use a:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE ...)
```

For the search query (in the documentation its advised for faster results) over an indexed colum,
the table structure is a very simple table

- id
- link (varchar 400)
- link_simhash (varchar 32)
- domain (varchar 200)
- flag 1 (bool)
- flag 2 (boll)
- bot_visit (int)
- date_found (date)
- date_crawled (date)

As i say'd the where is referring to the link hash.

Any ideas??? nobody??? whats wrong with my question???

Comment: What does the query you're using to look for duplicates look like?  Can you also post the structure of the table including the indexes and an `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: thank you for your comment (sadly- you are the only one) watch my edit...

Comment: Have you tried applying a constraint to your table to refuse queries where the hash already exists?  You could even just index it as unique.

Comment: Or simply change your subquery. Don't do a Select 1.  Do a Select count(*)  and you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Ryoku, using unique could trigger an unwanted error... i tested count(*) vs select 1 ... there is no difference because exists will return either null or 1 if founded. any more ideas??